# What if I use "Add missing constraints" option from storyboard, for assigning constraints in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

My question is that, can I trust on

> Resolve autolayout issues’ - “Add missing constraints”

option(as in the attached [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9pjS.png)), which automatically adds constraints to the objects present in the storyboard?

I used this and tried running the app in all screen formats and it works fine, so can I continue using this or is it wrong to consider “Add missing constraints” for the constraint design. I’m new to auto layout and any kind of response, explaining this concept will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's wrong. Even in your case described above, You can't say it work fine on all screen. Add missing constraints will only add constraints to satisfy the condition. It won't add constraints as according to your will.

Comment: and why would that be?I can perform add missing constraints first and then re-assign the constraints that I want to work in my way right?

Comment: it generates constraints automatically ... what if you don't want center-x and want top and bottom space ....

Comment: it's good, but mostly for the very basic cases, like f.e when you take one view and place it in the center of its superview (by using the guides). Unfortunately it doesn't work as good in more complex cases.

Comment: @LA complex cases, okay I'll keep that in mind. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the automatic constraint system is a **bad** idea.  Most of the time, it won't work dynamically for all screen sizes.  It generally adds constraints so objects appear correct in the current resolution you're designing in.

For example, it may pin a label you have placed in the center of an iPhone screen based on the distance from the left edge of the screen instead of the X value.  That distance from the edge is going to stay the same when you run it on an iPad and it's going to be significantly off-center to satisfy that constraint.

However, depending on the situation, it could pin them correctly (IE leading edges to the super view instead of a constant).  You *can* use the automatic constraint system for suggestions to reference what you need to add still, but I would not rely on it for dynamic UI.

Spend your time learning autolayout instead of throwing darts in the dark, it's really not as intimidating as it seems!

Answer (score 1):

No you should not trust. `Add missing constraints` will add constraints that are missing. It will not add constraints that's your design actually want.

So I suggest you to understand what constraint you'll require to complete UI.

`For every control, Compiler need to know its : **x,y,width and height**.

For example : You drag & drop UILabel on your xib. Now you add top space constraint. So compiler will give warning. Need constraint for : X position.

On above example width and height will take according to text of label. Now you had given top space so its y position is known.

But for X you didn't give any constraint. In this case if you use `Add missing constraints`. compiler will add constraint for x position according to your placement. It may be your require constraint or may be not.

Answer (score 0):

No iT just add the required constant so may be they are fixed so remove all constraints and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what the others say, "**Add Missing Contraints**" will always give the result of the layout that you desired. It's best that you learn to add constraints manually. But, there are times that you can be lazy for a couple of seconds by using that method but only for very simple layout.

I'll just share my thoughts about when should we use this method.

I use "Add Missing Constraints" when:

1. My layout is very much simple, it's like I know that when I do it automatically will yield the same result as doing it manually. This help saves a lot of time.
2. I am setting up constraints manually, but sometimes I don't know what constraints I am missing because the object that I am setting the constraints still shows red lines(missing constraints). This is just my purpose of learning.